# ConTeXt: Split xtables across multiple pages

Tags: page-breaking, context, pandoc, split, extreme-tables

## Background

Use [extreme tables](http://www.pragma-ade.com/general/manuals/xtables-mkiv.pdf) to split tabular data across pages.

## Problem

The `\setupxtable` command does not appear to be sufficient to force a table to split across pages.

Also, a reference to `split` is given twice (once in the setup and once in `startplacetable`), which seems redundant.

## Code

```
\setupxtable[
  split=yes,
  header=repeat,
]

\setupxtable[head][]
\setupxtable[body][]
\setupxtable[foot][]

\starttext
\dorecurse{2}{
    \input knuth \input ward
}

\startplacetable[here, split]
\startxtable
\startxtablehead[head]
\startxrow
\startxcell[align=right] Vendor \stopxcell
\startxcell[align=middle] Phone \stopxcell
\startxcell[align=middle] Contact \stopxcell
\startxcell[align=left] \$CAD \stopxcell
\startxcell[align=left] \$USD \stopxcell
\stopxrow
\stopxtablehead
\startxtablebody[body]
\dorecurse{9}{
    \startxrow
    \startxcell[align=right] Vendor \stopxcell
    \startxcell[align=middle] 555-1212 \stopxcell
    \startxcell[align=middle] Email \stopxcell
    \startxcell[align=left] 1234.58 \stopxcell
    \startxcell[align=left] 8256.76 \stopxcell
    \stopxrow
}
\stopxtablebody
\startxtablefoot[foot]
\startxrow
\startxcell[align=right] Vendor n\stopxcell
\startxcell[align=middle] 555-1212 \stopxcell
\startxcell[align=middle] Email \stopxcell
\startxcell[align=left] 1234.58 \stopxcell
\startxcell[align=left] 8256.76 \stopxcell
\stopxrow
\stopxtablefoot
\stopxtable
\stopplacetable

\stoptext
```

## Actual

The actual output is:

[image: No table split]

## Question

What needs to change in the code to cause part of the table to be on the first page while the remainder of the table is on the second page, such that the header row is repeated?

## Constraints

The code is generated, mostly, by pandoc.

## Environment

Running:

```
mtx-context     | current version: 2018.09.13 17:41
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use the `placetable` environment you gave to pass a placement and option keywords to the `location` key which will end in the first argument of the `\placetable` command.

When you take a look at the syntax of the `\placetable` command you can see that `options`, `references` and the `caption` use separate arguments.

[image: Arguments for the placetable command]

The `placeable` environment on the other hand uses only a single argument (the second argument is for `userdata` where you can pass whetever you want) where each argument type is passed to a key.

[image: Arguments for the startplacetable command]

To break your table across pages you have to change the line

```
\startplacetable[here, split]
```

to

```
\startplacetable[location={here, split}]
```

where you pass the `split` keyword to the `location` key of the `\startplacetable` command.