# ConTeXt: Allow all floating extreme tables to split across pages

Tags: tables, page-breaking, context

## Background

Using Pandoc to generate tables that are sourced from an R Markdown document.

## Problem

Pandoc does not have a way to override the code generated for a Markdown table. As such, there does not seem to be a way to instruct Pandoc to include `here` or `split`. That is, Pandoc cannot generate the following code:

```
\startplacetable[location={here, split}]
```

## Minimum Working Example

The following code shows the problem:

```
\starttext
\startplacetable[title={Average Annual Temperatures}]
\startxtable
\startxtablehead[head]
\startxrow
\startxcell[align=middle,width={0.10\textwidth}] Year \stopxcell
\startxcell[align=middle,width={0.14\textwidth}] Value \stopxcell
\stopxrow
\stopxtablehead
\startxtablebody[body]
\dorecurse{100}{%
\startxrow
\startxcell[align=middle,width={0.10\textwidth}] 1880 \stopxcell
\startxcell[align=middle,width={0.14\textwidth}] 0.1146 \stopxcell
\stopxrow}
\stopxtablebody
\startxtablefoot[foot]
\startxrow
\startxcell[align=middle,width={0.10\textwidth}] 2018 \stopxcell
\startxcell[align=middle,width={0.14\textwidth}] 1.014 \stopxcell
\stopxrow
\stopxtablefoot
\stopxtable
\stopplacetable
\stoptext
```

This produces:

[image: No Table Split]

[Changing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/453099/2148) the `startplacetable` command options produces the desired result, but requires modifying the output generated from pandoc:

```
\startplacetable[title={Average Annual Temperatures}, location={here,split}]
```

Splitting across pages is enabled:

[image: Split Table]

## Ideas

My first instinct was to change the setups for table:

```
\setupfloat[table][location={here,split}]
```

This didn't work because the `location` [parameter](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/setupfloat) for the `\setupfloat` macro is different than the `location` option for the `\startplacetable` macro.

In the past, I've used `sed` in shell scripts to replace `\startplacetable` with `\startplacetable[location={split}]`, but that's a brittle solution.

Using `\setupxtable`'s `split=yes` option doesn't work, either, probably because the extreme table is embedded within a captioned float:

```
\setupxtable[frame=off,split=yes,header=repeat,footer=repeat]
```

Another idea is to redefine `\startplacetable`. Something like:

```
\def\oldstartplacetable\startplacetable

\define[1]\startplacetable{
  \oldstartplacetable[#1,location={split}]
}
```

That doesn't compile, though.

## Question

Without changing the code generated by pandoc, how would you allow all extreme tables inside a `\startplacetable` environment to split across pages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default location for floats is not called `location` but `default`.

```
\setupfloat[table][default={here,split}]
```